# An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid Django Rest + Vercel

Tags: amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, boto3, vercel

I get this error:

> "An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid."

When I create object from django rest admin panel in vercel server and when I create it in local it works. How to integrate `aws s3` + `vercel` to django?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.